# Rails 3.1 javascript after asset precompile stop working; production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, assets, asset-pipeline

For some reason my site was working perfectly one second. However, i realized that there is a css error so i decide to fix it by doing assets:precompile. Once I did that my entire site messed up. none of the javascript works anymore. However css still works. Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix that. I have no idea where I can start or debug. Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you javascript files get loaded or not? And please take a look at `public/assets` - are there any js files?

Comment: Dear @LimboPeng
It seems to be loaded as I tried to click view source and it does link to an application.js1234092814309. When i click on it there is javacode in there. There are also items in public/assets. So everything seems to be working except the javascript doesnt' run.

Comment: What browser are you using? If Firefox/Chrome, is there any error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: How do you check the javascript console on chrome. I have however tried playing more with the application.js file. 

It used to be 

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fileupload
//= require jquery.fileupload-ui
//= require jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery.nivo.slider
//= require jquery.nivo.slider.pack
//= require_tree .

now i got rid of everything below require jquery_us except for tree and jquery start working again. However I still cannot get nivoslider to start. Any reason why?

Regards,Kane

Comment: Open the page with Chrome, press `F12` on your keyboard, and then click the "Console".

Comment: I figured it out. I need to get rid of all the //= require after jquery_ujs and just do a javascript_include_tag jquery.nivo.slider.pack at home.erb.html. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to get rid of all the //= require after jquery_ujs and just do a javascript_include_tag jquery.nivo.slider.pack at home.erb.html. Thanks for all the help.